# 'setfacl' permissions don't apply to directories created by git clone?

Tags: permissions, git, chmod, acl

Here's how I am setting permissions for my website's root directory i.e. `~/public_html`, where the files that my website serves are placed:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data ~/public_html
chmod g+s ~/public_html
chmod g+rwx ~/public_html
setfacl -m d:g:www-data:rwx ~/public_html
```

- **Command #1** gives "www-data" group ownership access to `~/public_html`;
- **#2** sets the group ID, so that all new directories/files within are also owned by "www-data" group
- **#3** sets access permissions for the group "www-data" on the directory to 775;
- **#4** makes sure that the same apply to all new directories/files created within `~/public_html`.

It's working great, as it should. All new created directories and files inherit the forced permissions.

The problem is with directories created by `git clone` (after I do `cd ~/public_html && git clone ....`).

**UPDATED:** The directory **DOES** inherit the group ID (i.e. "www-data" owns the newly created directory), **BUT NOT** the access permissions (775 for directories and 664 for files). Also, it's just the top-level directory that git creates. Every directory and file withing inherit permissions just as they should. Could it be that the Debian git package doesn't have the [fix for this bug](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/commit/?id=45d4fdc2dc74c657a9c2e95bf04aed539fdcb0a4) yet?

What am I doing wrong? Rather, how exactly should I be doing it?

Comment: If you use the SGID bit then the ACL should be: `d:g::rwx`

Comment: @HaukeLaging Yes, I now see it that it's kinda redundant, if that's what you meant. But that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `git` overwrites the GID and the ACLs after the files have been created (like a simple `mv` does when moving cross device). You can check that by running it through strace (`strace -f -o git.strace -e trace=file`).

Comment: The `strace` command isn't working. Am I supposed to replace `file` in the command with something? If yes, what?

Comment: @its_me The command should create a file with the name `git.strace`. `trace=file` is correct; that limits the trace output to file related syscalls.

Comment: Something's wrong with the command. I get usage instructions showing valid options and stuff, when I run the command.

Comment: @its_me are you putting the command you're running at the end of the strace command? I think Hauke meant for that to be implied.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Sorry for the delay; unexpected problem on my PC. Here's the output of strace: http://pastebin.com/RVbiaaXy . It has this line `mkdir("dropplets", 0755)          = 0` -- so, does it mean, Git is forcing the directory permissions, and thereby not adhering to ACLs? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @its_me No, that's the normal syscall. The 0755 is overwritten by the default ACL. You can see that when comparing the strace output of a `mkdir acldir/subdir` with `cp -a sourcedir acldir`. In the second case the `mkdir()` syscall is followed by a `chmod` (at least if necessary). Unfortunately `chmod()` and the like are not shown with `-e trace=file` (which surprises me) so you have to leave that out. But you can reduce the output to those lines affecting a single file or directory. The endless repetitions are useless.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Tried my best. No clue where's it changing. I am starting to think it's this bug: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/commit/?id=45d4fdc2dc74c657a9c2e95bf04aed539fdcb0a4 (please see my edits to the question as well). Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing different permissions using `git clone` then it's likely your `umask` which is causing this:

```
$ umask
0002
```

The new files being created when you run the `git clone` command are being created with permissions based on what your `umask` specifies. Umask says which bits should be masked off. So in the above example any new files I create with a umask of `0002` would have the other write bit turned off.

#### References

- [What is Umask and How To Setup Default umask Under Linux?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)
- [git clone produces different permissions on different servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519864/git-clone-produces-different-permissions-on-different-servers)

Comment: I don't think so (although I am not sure). I think Git is actually setting the directory permissions to `0755`. Please read this comment for more info: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80267/setfacl-permissions-dont-apply-to-directories-created-by-git-clone#comment118345_80269 and let me know what you think

Comment: I think your issue might ultimately be this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637416/git-clone-respects-umask-except-for-top-level-project-directory. See the comments on the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, that's where I found the bug (linked in my question). The thing is, the fix was released in January, and doubt it isn't yet been included in the Debian package.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `git` is failing to clone the extended attributes of the `public_html` directory.

ACLs (as well as SELinux file labels) under Linux are implemented using filesystem-based extended attributes (see man pages for attr, getfattr, setfattr).  Extended attributes must be explicitly copied in order for them to be preserved.  Most file utilities (mv, cp, tar, rsync, rm, et al.) in most modern Linux distros were updated to support extended attributes (and, by extension, ACLs).

Redo your strace but leave out the `-e trace=file` part, pipe it to `grep xattr`, and then see if there are any calls to setxattr.

`strace -f 2>&1 git clone | grep xattr`

If you see no output, then git, or at least the one you're using, doesn't support extended attributes.